# Angular JS directive loading explained

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm looking to understand the expected behavior of angular directives when a page is loaded once then returned to using routing.  If I have a the directive below on a page, the `debugger` line is reached when the page is first loaded.  When I navigate away from that page to another page with a different controller, then return to the original page with the directive, the directive doesn't load.  Is that the expected behavior when dealing with different controllers?  Or should the directive `link` be called every time the page is loaded regardless?

```
app.directive('directive1', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        debugger;
        console.log('directive loaded');
    }
   }
});
```

It's on the page like this

```
<directive1 id="mydirective" style="height:100%;"></directive1>
```

The flow is like this

```
pg1.htm(directive)/controller1 --> pg2.htm/controller2 --> back to pg1.htm(directive)/controller1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is SPA, you are moving inside the AngularJS App, the directive is not loaded everytime. But once you refresh the page it will be loaded.

Comment: Does that mean you shouldn't instantiate objects in the directive that the page controller relies on?  That's what I'm doing and it's not working.  Also, you mention refreshing the page, do you mean manually by the user or from the controller?